# Exporting Excel Charts as Images

Tags: c#, excel, export, excel-interop

I've written the following simple C# console application to export all the charts from an Excel Workbook.  It works just fine **unless the chart has not been scrolled to since opening the document**, in which case an empty image file is generated.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ExcelExporter
{
    class ChartExporter
    {
        const string EXPORT_TO_DIRECTORY = @"C:\Users\Sandy\Desktop\Excel\Charts";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application app = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;

            ConsoleColor c = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write("Export To: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = c;
            string exportPath = Console.ReadLine();

            if (exportPath == "")
                exportPath = EXPORT_TO_DIRECTORY;

            Excel.Workbook wb = app.ActiveWorkbook;

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
            {
                Excel.ChartObjects chartObjects = (Excel.ChartObjects)(ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing));

                foreach (Excel.ChartObject co in chartObjects)
                {
                    Excel.Chart chart = (Excel.Chart)co.Chart;
//                  app.Goto(co, true);
                    chart.Export(exportPath + @"\" + chart.Name + ".png", "PNG", false);
                }
            }

            Process.Start(exportPath);
        }
    }
}
```

I've made a few failed attempts to scroll to the object; the commented out line towards the bottom of the program (`app.Goto(co, true);`) for example only works for ranges.  **Is there any way to scroll to `ChartObject`s, or otherwise ensure that they properly export to images?**

For testing, use a workbook with charts 1000+ rows down (far enough that they are unquestionably out of view when the document opens); close and reopen the document before running the program (once scrolled to, the charts will have already been rendered and stored in memory).

Comment: You could try setting the Excel instance visibility to true before exporting.

Comment: @TimWilliams [`_Application.Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.visible.aspx)?  I'll try it.

Comment: @TimWilliams no dice =\  same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA, but same idea would likely work for C#...

```
Dim co As ChartObject, sht As Worksheet, x As Long
x = 1
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
    Application.Goto co.TopLeftCell, True
    co.Chart.Export "C:\_stuff\test\chart" & x & ".jpg", "JPG", False
    x = x + 1
Next co
```

Comment: Worked wonders (and so fast, too!).  For anyone looking for the C# equivalent (as it would fit in my code above):  `app.Goto(co.TopLeftCell, true);`

Answer (score 4):

I found the following worked for me

```
            foreach (Excel.ChartObject co in chartObjects)
            {
                co.Select();
                Excel.Chart chart = (Excel.Chart)co.Chart;
                chart.Export(exportPath + @"\" + chart.Name + ".png", "PNG", false);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 3.1 using Interop.Excel and changing the COM ref in VS to Copy Local

```
   private static void ExportExcelChart()
    {
        var excelApp = new excel.Application(); 
        var wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"z:\scratch\acme_inc.xlsx");
        var ws = (excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];
        var chartObjects= ws.ChartObjects() as IEnumerable;

        foreach (excel.ChartObject co in chartObjects)
        { 
            co.Select();
            excel.Chart chart = (excel.Chart)co.Chart;
            chart.Export($@"z:\{chart.Name}.png", "PNG", false);
        }
        wb.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
```