# How to export Chart created in EPPlus to Image file

Tags: c#, xlsx, epplus

I have tried this;

```
var excelPicture = sheet.Drawings[0] as OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture;
var img = excelPicture.Image;
```

However the excelPicture variable become null. How can I create image file from ExcelDrawing??

Comment: If you're open to using another library, you should look into oxyplot: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot

I use this to embed images into reports in an internal API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this can't be done via EPPlus API. There is the opened issue in the GitHub project repository [how export the drawings to a file](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/171). But the provided [solution](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/171#issuecomment-463969796) in the question does not work (it seems @Onchomngebul himself wrote the the comment)

Alternative solution is to use `Workbook` class in [Spire.XLS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.XLS/) nuget-package (or via free version [FreeSpire.XLS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.XLS/)).

```
var workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(workbookFileName, ExcelVersion.Version2010);
var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]; // index or name of your worksheet
var image = workbook.SaveChartAsImage(sheet, 0); // chart index
img.Save(chartFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

For more details please see this [comment](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/171#issuecomment-376735929) in the issue.

Another solution is to try to use [Excel.ChartObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject). I think this question [Exporting Excel Charts as Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211473/exporting-excel-charts-as-images) may help you.