# Interop Excel Charts Exported to Image appear incomplete

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, excel-interop, export-to-image

I am trying to export chart to image in .Net Azure functions. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211473/exporting-excel-charts-as-images)  link. But
the exported image appears incomplete.

Expected Image:

[image]

Actual Exported Image:

[image]

**.Net Core 3.1 Azure Function Project**

COM Reference used: **Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library (version 1.9)**

Identity: **Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**

Code:

```
var app = new Application();
var wkBook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\MTA\Project_X.xlsx");
var wkSheet = (Worksheet)wkBook.Sheets["Overall MTA Chart"];
wkSheet.Select();
var charts = wkSheet.ChartObjects() as IEnumerable;
foreach (ChartObject item in charts)
{
    item.Select();
    var chart = (Chart)item.Chart;
    chart.Export($@"D:\MTA\{chart.Name}.png", "PNG", true);
}
```

Comment: Is that triangle actually part of the chart? Or just floating in front of it?

Comment: I think its just floating in front. This is all I received as requirement. When I click on it, excel shows 'AutoShape 5'. Is there any way entire group can be taken as screenshot?

Comment: You might be able to group the shapes together?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure azure functions can support `Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` since this needs excel to be installed.

I suggest you use a different library to achieve this.
(if azure functions can support, this is not the answer for you)

For an example if you use [FreeSpire.XLS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.XLS/)

```
var workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(workbookFileName, excel version);
var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
var image = workbook.SaveChartAsImage(sheet, 0);
image.Save(chartImageFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```